# NullException in Multi-thread Tree Search

Tags: c#, multithreading, search, tree

I have a constructor for a `class` called `ActNode` which takes a `class` parameter called `Act` like this:

```
public Act Act; //the act affiliated with this node...
public ActNode(Act moAct, ...some others, not important) {
  if (moAct == null)
      throw new SomeException(); //this is never entered
  Act = moAct;
  ... some other codes
}
```

The constructor above is the only constructor the `ActNode` has and anywhere in the code, the `Act` passed to the constructor is not `null`. Then, in one of the `ActNode`'s methods, a `bool` flag of the `Act` is checked like this:

```
public void ActNodeMethod() { 
  if (Act.AnActFlagToBeChecked) { //FIXME this Act can be surprisingly null!
      //do something
  }
}
```

Thus, in a single thread environment, the `Act.AnActFlagToBeChecked` cannot throw `NullException` since the `Act` of an `ActNode` cannot be `null`. However, I use the `ActNode` in a multi-thread environment. It is not always, but sometimes the line above:

```
if (Act.AnActFlagToBeChecked) //FIXME this Act can be surprisingly null!
```

Can throw `null` exception.

Why is this so and how to fix it?

From reading a post in SO, it is said that this may happen if the `Act` is not initialized (therefore having default value of `null`) but the method is called. Yet in my implementation, there is no such case, because the `Act` everywhere in the code is never `null` when the constructor is called.

The only thing here is that I implement it in multi-thread environment where multiple `ActNode`s can call `ActNodeMethod` at the same time. But it shouldn't be a problem (or it *could*?) since each `ActNode` will have its own resource called `Act` associated to it (not a *shared* resource).

I am pretty confused here and would appreciate if someone can help enlightment me of the possible issues of the above implementation.

---

To give bigger context, `ActNode` is a `TreeNode` which I use to store a value representing the time needed to go to that node. I implement the `ActNode` in my searching tree algorithm to find the fastest solution to finish up a set of given "`Act`s". I use multi-threads because it can speed up the searching process.

Comment: Where is the definition of `AnActFlagToBeChecked`? Also, by using the same name for the type *and* the field it's quite possible that you refer to an uninitialized field. Or you may refer to a static field that isn't initialized. Or whatever.

Comment: Are you sure it's `Act == null` and not one of its properties? Is it possible the instance of `ActNode` constructed without using constructor (e.g. by reflection)? It's public field, so something else can set it to `null` (make it -getter-only property).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the field `AnActFlagToBeChecked` is a `public bool` (not `static`) - it is either `true` of `false`. It is the `Act` which can be `null` - And I am confused because of that

Comment: Post the *full* exception message, as generated by `Exception.ToString()`. The call trace will show where exactly the exception occured

Comment: @Ian without the source code it's almost impossible to help. It could be anything. Some other method setting the field to null. Or the constructor may get an actual null parameter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK, the error log is not in my PC where I posted this question, thus I cannot do it now. But I will post it as soon as I get back to my office's PC.

Comment: @Ian add a null check to the parameters as well. `moAct` may just be null. You know, all this is available in the well known duplicate.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the `Act` itself is never set to `null` and the constructor never gets `null` parameter. Those two I can guarantee... But given the snippet of the code above alone - is there any possible issue?

Comment: Try to make the `Act` field `final` to ensure it cannot be changed somewhere else. Furthermore do a `null` check within the constructor.

Comment: @StanleyF. here I simplify the code - but yes, actually the `Act` in the constructor is never null -> this I can tell

Comment: Not `final`, readonly! And without a null check there is no guarantee

Comment: @StanleyF. `final` is java keyword, no?

Comment: Hi @Ian, any additional info on this? Also which `TreeNode` class do you have in mind?

Comment: @IvanStoev hi Ivan, I was away in the last couple of days. And yes, I haven't updated this for a while. The `TreeNode` class I use is the `TreeNode` for `System.Windows.Forms` Any idea?

Comment: Well, nothing concrete of course, but I'm always suspicious when using WF UI related class from multiple threads. Some things to try: (1) make the field `readonly` and make sure it's only set in the constructor to non null value. (2) Make sure there is no other constructor, even private. (3) Override `Clone` method and make sure it's not called. (4) Make sure there is no binary deserialization involved. It can create objects w/o calling any constructor! I guess that's enough for now, if you can provide reproducible example, I'll be glad to look at it.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for the suggestions. You are suggesting that the issue may possibly be in the `TreeNode` class for multiple threads. OK, let me look at that. The difficulty I found to solve this issue is actually because the error does *not* always occur and that the code is now already used in the "Live" system. :( Thus, I only get the error log *after* the error occurs (not *when* the error occurs) and when I am around monitoring the live system, the error does not occur!! Arrghh (frustrated)! That's why it is *not* easily reproduceable. But thanks, will look into that too.

Comment: @Ian Oh boy, I know what you mean :( Good luck! (hope at least it's not running in radioactive environment :)

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks. Fortunately, this time it is *not* in a radioactive environment. ;)